# The number of inputs I have to enter is one more than required for the output to display

Tags: c, input

I have to enter one more input than required for the code to start running. For example, for 2 strings I have to enter 3 strings, only then the output shows. Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main () {
    int num_strings;
    char arr[num_strings][100];
    scanf("%d",&num_strings); 
    for (int i=0;i<=num_strings-1;i++) {
        scanf("%s\n",&arr[i]);
        
    }
    for (int j=0;j<=num_strings-1;j++) {
        if (strlen(arr[j])>10) {
            printf("%c%d%c",arr[j][0],strlen(arr[j])-2,arr[j][strlen(arr[j])-1]);
            printf("\n");
        } else {
            printf("%s",arr[j]);
            printf("\n");
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s\n",&arr[i]);` should be `scanf("%s",&arr[i]);`,
 `scanf()` keeps on reading and ignores after a non whitespace is found.

Comment: Aside: `i<=num_strings-1` is more classically understood as `i < num_strings`.

Comment: Thanks Alex, yeah it does very nicely, also Oka input noted just beginning out.

Comment: When you declare the 2D array 'char arr[num_strings][100];', what value will the generated code use for 'num_strings'?

Answer (score 1):

The following

```
int num_strings;
char arr[num_strings][100];
scanf("%d",&num_strings);
```

is out of order. Changing the value of `num_strings` does not retroactively adjust the size of arrays that were initialized using this variable. As such, `arr` is initialized with an *indeterminate* value, since `num_strings` is uninitialized. This is an example of invoking [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

`&arr[i]` is of type `char (*)[100]`, you simply want `arr[i]`, which will *decay* to a `char *` (the correct type for `%s`) when passed to `scanf`.

Remove the trailing whitespace from the `scanf` format, or it will hang until it reads non-whitespace (`"%s\n"` -> `"%s"`).

Limit the length of the strings you read with a *field-width specifier* as to not overflow the buffers (`%99s`).

`strlen` returns a `size_t`, the format specifier for printing this is `%zu`.

Note that `scanf` can fail for a variety of reasons. Consider checking that the return value of each call was (or was not) the expected *number of conversions*, e.g.,

```
if (2 != scanf("%d%d", &a, &b))
    /* failure */;
```

and handle any failures.

Here is a functional version of your program, without error checking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int num_strings;

    scanf("%d", &num_strings);

    char arr[num_strings][100];

    for (int i = 0; i < num_strings; i++)
        scanf("%99s", arr[i]);

    for (int j = 0; j < num_strings; j++) {
        if (strlen(arr[j]) > 10) {
            printf("%c%zu%c\n",
                    arr[j][0], strlen(arr[j]) - 2,
                    arr[j][strlen(arr[j]) - 1]);
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", arr[j]);
        }
    }

}
```

`stdin`:

```
3
hello
thisisalongerstring
world
```

`stdout`:

```
hello
t17g
world
```